# Раздельная компиляция шаблонной функции члена нешаблонного класса

Tags: c++, классы, функции, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь разобраться в синтаксисе раздельной компиляции шаблонной функции члена нешаблонного класса. Работаю в Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Вот мой *.h файл в котором есть шаблонная функция член `SetBuffer`

```
#pragma once

class Message
{
public:
    Message();
    ~Message();

public:
    template <typename TBuffer>
    void SetBuffer(const TBuffer& buffer);

private:
    std::string buffer_;
};
```

Далее представлен *.cpp файл

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Message.h"

Message::Message()
{ }

Message::~Message()
{ }

template <typename TBuffer> void Message<TBuffer>::SetBuffer(const TBuffer& buffer)
{
    buffer;
}
```

При компиляции я получаю вот такие ошибки:

```
    Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  D:\programming\c++\pp_samples\modules\_template\class_template\src\Message.cpp  10  1   class_template
    Error   2   error C2182: 'Message' : illegal use of type 'void' D:\programming\c++\pp_samples\modules\_template\class_template\src\Message.cpp  10  1   class_template
    Error   3   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition D:\programming\c++\pp_samples\modules\_template\class_template\src\Message.cpp  10  1   class_template
    Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : '<' D:\programming\c++\pp_samples\modules\_template\class_template\src\Message.cpp  10  1   class_template
    Error   5   error C2039: 'SetBuffer' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  D:\programming\c++\pp_samples\modules\_template\class_template\src\Message.cpp  10  1   class_template
```

Компилятору судя по всему не нравится определение или обьявление шаблонной функции члена `SetBuffer`. Какой правильный синтаксис для шаблонной функции члена нешаблонного класса при раздельной компиляции ?? Спасибо!!

Comment: Класс Message не является шаблонным. Поэтому данное выражение Message<TBuffer>::SetBuffer является некорректным. И поместите определение функции в заголовочный файл, где определен сам класс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам класс `Message` не является шаблонным. А поэтому данное квалифицированное имя

```
Message<TBuffer>::SetBuffer
```

некорректное.

И поместите определение функции в заголовочный файл, где класс определен. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class Message
{
public:
    Message();
    ~Message();

public:
    template <typename TBuffer>
    void SetBuffer(const TBuffer& buffer);

private:
    std::string buffer_;
};

template <typename TBuffer> 
void Message::SetBuffer(const TBuffer& buffer)
{
    buffer;
}

int main() 
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: определить функцию `SetBuffer` в *.cpp файле не получится?

Comment: @SpaceRabbit Каждая единица компиляции должна включать определение функции, чтобы из него вывести экземпляр не шаблонной функции. Поэтому определение функции должно быть там, где ее объявление.

Comment: понял, спасибо.